# Identifying different users in the same servlet

Tags: java, session, tomcat, servlets, server

Say I have a servlet with a list of rooms, in each room there can be several users and each user will see a page with his own state, suppose it's a game and each user has his own board.

Suppose I have two servlets: `rooms`and `singleRoom`.

If the user sends a request to the `singleRoom` servlet, how can it know to identify and handle his request with the context of that user's state on the server?

Does the client side need to attach a session id to the user's request and match it with the list of users state on the server?

What if the same user is in more than one room? He will have the same session but two states on the server.

Is there another way to do this than to use the session id?

Comment: No other way than the "session-id" *as a principle*. Sure, you can replace it with a cookie, request variable/parameter, or whatever else you like, but there will be something than need to come from the client to tell you every time in which "specific interaction context" that request comes - as the "session id" is already there and does that for you, why re-invent the wheel?

Comment: Well using just the session id will be a problem if the same user will have two states on the server... I thought maybe i'll add to the session id an object address of the room he's in or hash that room to get more specific identifiers.

Comment: Your problem has the same solution as the one of "detect if the same user is logged-in twice". Are you able to solve it?

Comment: Well I'm not sure it's the same problem, in the "logged-in twice" problem you can solve it by having a 1 to 1 relationship between session id and state, but in my problem this is not enough. @AdrianColomitchi

Comment: How can you **detect** a user is logged-in twice?

Comment: I can hold a list of names of users and check that, or check a list of session ids. I still don't see how it helps... @AdrianColomitchi

Comment: Well, add to this list the info about what is the place where the user has last seen and validate the transition between "where last seen transition to what's the new place in the current request".